# objective-c iphone how to get data from xml file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I have an xml file that contains this data:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <WordList>
    <Words id="1">
       <sixletterword>LEVERS</sixletterword>
       <smallerwords>
         <word>EEL</word>
         <word>ERE</word>
         <word>EVE</word>
         <word>LEE</word>
         <word>SEE</word>
         <word>EELS</word>
         <word>ELSE</word>
         <word>EVER</word>
         <word>LEER</word>
         <word>LEES</word>
         <word>REEL</word>
         <word>SEER</word>
         <word>VEER</word>
         <word>ELVES</word>
         <word>LEERS</word>
         <word>LEVER</word>
         <word>REELS</word>
         <word>REVEL</word>
         <word>SERVE</word>
         <word>SEVER</word>
         <word>VEERS</word>
         <word>VERSE</word>
         <word>LEVERS</word>
         <word>REVELS</word>
       </smallerwords>
    </Words>
    <Words id="2">
       <sixletterword>ADULTS</sixletterword>
       <smallerwords>
         <word>ADS</word>
         <word>LAD</word>
         <word>SAD</word>
         <word>SAT</word>
         <word>TAD</word>
         <word>DUAL</word>
         <word>DUST</word>
         <word>LADS</word>
         <word>LAST</word>
         <word>LAUD</word>
         <word>LUST</word>
         <word>SALT</word>
         <word>SLAT</word>
         <word>STUD</word>
         <word>ADULT</word>
         <word>LAUDS</word>
         <word>ADULTS</word>
       </smallerwords>
    </Words>
  </WordList>`
```

My question is, how do I parse it and get the data? Also, once it is parsed, how is it represented and accessed?

PS: this is a huuuuge list of words, and performance is key here when using a parser. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of TBXML (http://tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html)?
Try it!

You should also check out this link - http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

"As you can see here, NSXMLParser was the slowest method by far. TBXML was the fastest, which makes sense because many features were taken out in order to optimize parse time for reading only."

Comment: This one looks promising and easier than just using the default xml parser. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Yep, I was able to read that article, thanks a lot for the reference! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that shows XML parsing using **GDataXMLParser**.

[how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)